# Linear functionals separate point and closed subspace of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a real Banach space and $S$ a closed subspace of $\mathcal{B}$. I want to prove that for $f_0 \notin S$, there is a linear functional $l$ such that $l(f) = 0$ for all $f \in S$ and $l(f_0) = 1$. Furthermore, we may arrange so that $\|l\|_{\mathcal{B}^\ast} = 1/d(f_0,S)$.

To do this we consider the gauge function $p$ on $\mathcal{B}$ defined by $p(f) = d(f,S)/d(f_0,S)$. As $S$ is closed it is clear that $d(f_0,S) \neq 0$ so this is well-defined and furthermore $p(f) = 0$ for all $f\in S$. $p$ is semi-additive by the triangle inequality and I believe $d(\alpha f,S) = \alpha d(f,S)$ because $S$ is a subspace. Now consider the linear functional $l_0$ on $V_0 := \operatorname{Span} {f_0}$ defined by $l(\alpha f_0) = \alpha$. Then we have $l(v) \leq p(v)$ for all $v \in V_0$ and Hahn-Banach gives the existence of $l$ on $V$ so that $l(v) \leq p(v)$ for all $v \in \mathcal{B}$.

> > **My question is:** However, I am not able to arrange for $l$ to be so that $\|l\| = 1/d(f_0,S)$, how can we do this? I have also constructed such an $l$ using a different gauge function but it's not really relevant for it doesn't involve the distance function $d(f,S)$.

Comment: $\lVert l\rVert = 1/d(f_0,S)$ follows from $p(f) = d(f,S)/d(f_0,S)$ and $l(f_0) = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer However $f_0$ is not necessarily of norm $1$, is this a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem. You know that $\lVert f_0\rVert \geqslant d(f_0,S)$. You know a little more, and that little more is what you need to show that $\lVert l\rVert = 1/d(f_0,S)$. Do you want to try yourself first?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes.

Comment: @DanielFischer This is what I get. From $l(f) \leq p(f)$ we have $||l|| \leq \sup_{||f|| = 1} d(f,S)/d(f_0,S)$. Since $0\in S$, the numerator for a fixed $f$ is $\leq$ $||f||$ and so the supremum is less than or equal to $1/d(f_0,S)$. Hence $||l|| \leq 1/d(f_0,S)$. At the moment I can't get the reverse inequality.

Comment: For any subset $M \subset \mathcal{B}\setminus\{0\}$, you have $$\lVert l \rVert \geqslant \sup_{m\in M} \frac{\lvert l(m)\rvert}{\lVert m\rVert}.$$ Choose a good $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction yields $\lVert l\rVert = 1/d(f_0,S)$. On the one hand, since $d(f,S) \leqslant \lVert f\rVert$ for all $f\in\mathcal{B}$, we have

$$\lvert l(f)\rvert \leqslant p(f) = \frac{d(f,S)}{d(f_0,S)} \leqslant \frac{1}{d(f_0,S)}\lVert f\rVert \Rightarrow \lVert l\rVert \leqslant \frac{1}{d(f_0,S)}.$$

On the other hand, we have

$$\lVert l\rVert \geqslant \sup_{s\in S} \frac{\lvert l(f_0-s)\rvert}{\lVert f_0-s\rVert} = \sup_{s\in S} \frac{1}{\lVert f_0-s\rVert} = \frac{1}{\inf\limits_{s\in S} \lVert f_0-s\rVert} = \frac{1}{d(f_0,S)}.$$