# Show that $^{\perp}(M^{\perp})=\overline{M}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following

> Let $X$ be normed linear space and $M$ be subspace of $X$ and $N$ be subspace of $X^*$. Define $$M^{\perp}=\{\varphi\in X^{*}:\varphi(x)=0\text{ for all }x\in M\}$$ and $$^{\perp}N=\{x\in X:\varphi(x)=0\text{ for all }\varphi\in N\}$$
> I'm trying to show that $$^{\perp}(M^{\perp})=\overline{M}$$ where $\overline{M}$ is the closure of $M$

I assume to show the equality, we need to show the containment of both directions, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in\overline{M}$ and take $\varphi\in X^*$ so that $\varphi\in M^\bot$, i.e. $\varphi\vert_M=0$, i.e. $\varphi(y)=0$ for all $y\in M$. Since $x\in\overline{M}$, we have that there exists a sequence $(y_n)\subset M$ with $y_n\to x$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous (as $\varphi\in X^*$) we have that $\varphi(x)=\lim_n\varphi(y_n)=0$. This shows that $x\in  ^\bot(M^\bot)$, so $\overline{M}\subset^\bot(M^\bot)$.

Now for the other inclusion, let $x\in ^\bot(M^\bot)$ and assume that $x\not\in\overline{M}$. Now $\overline{M}$ is a closed subspace, so by Hahn-Banach (functionals separate points and closed subspaces) we can find a functional $f\in X^*$ so that $f\vert_{\overline{M}}=0$ and $f(x)\neq0$. But this is a contradiction, since $f\in M^\bot$, and thus since $x\in ^\bot(M^\bot)$ it should be $f(x)=0$. We assumed that $x\not\in\overline{M}$ and we reached a contradiction, so $x\in\overline{M}$ and this proves the reverse inclusion.

Comment: I think a bit of work should be done to show that $f|_{\overline{M}}$ can be chosen to be zero.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan What kind of work? It is a classical consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem that, given a closed subspace and a point outside of it, we can find a functional that assigns a non-zero value to the point and vanishes identically on the closed subspace. This is taught almost in every functional analysis course when Hahn-Banach is presented.

Comment: 1. I don't think it is reasonable to assume that this is taught in "almost every" functional analysis course, unless you claim to have attended all such courses.  2. It is not a matter of whether this is standard knowledge or not. OP's question is also standard and classical. It is about making an easily read, accessible, and *self-contained* answer.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555432/linear-functionals-separate-point-and-closed-subspace-of-banach-space

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565274/existence-of-bounded-linear-functional-that-maps-elements-of-normed-space-to-dis

Are two answers on MSE and about 10 pdfs in a mere google search enough for you to consider that something is well-established?

Comment: I did not claim otherwise. Again, OP's question is also a well-established result. I am simply saying that in the context of OP's question that the fact you reference may not be known or obvious to them, so it doesn't hurt to explicate just a bit.